# Summing a column based on what month it is....how do I do this?

Tags: excel

I receive external data every month. I'd like to automate this process, and I have hit a snag. I can do the ins and outs of the automation, but I'm struggling with the summation. I get data in a grid, the number of rows varies and while the columns are fixed, 12 of them are spend in specific months. It is that which is needed.

I have solved the issue of the variable row number for the summation. It's the column that is escaping me. Say for example I want it to count up all the April values, getting it to count along the columns and count everything below has been where the issue is.
I've looked at INDEX, MATCH, OFFSET, COUNT I know there is an answer in there somewhere. The best I can get is this:

`=SUMIFS(L5:INDIRECT("W"&COUNT(A:A)+4),L4:W4,"4")`

`Where the data starts at L5. 12 months along gives W, and the variable row number (the first 3 rows are blank and the 4th row is a header)`

`L4:W4 are the month headers`

`4 is for example what it is looking for: I have a MONTH(TODAY)-1 in there normally as when it looks at last month's numbers, but for the sake of formula building I've settled on a constant until I've got the syntax and logic correct.`

I'd expect it to look through L4 to W4, find '4' and sum everything in that range defined by the range. What I get is #VALUE!

Answer (score 1):

SUMIF is not needed a simple sum with INDEX()/MATCH() to return the correct column will suffice.

Also with SUM there is no reason to not use full column references:

```
=SUM(INDEX(L5:W1040000,0,MATCH(4,L4:W4,0)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks.I'm not using full column references as there is more data below. I blended it all together, including the variable month and it worked. Now to get the macros written. Thanks again, you've made my day!